# Unable to print SVG images created by Raphael in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, raphael

I have generated a graph using Raphael. Now when I am trying to print the graph using the following code:

```
var data = document.getElementById("Graph").innerHTML;
var mywindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'height=400,width=600');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title></head><body >');
mywindow.document.write(data);
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
mywindow.print();
mywindow.close();
return true;
window.print();
```

The graph is showing up in a new window along with the print dialog in all browsers.
The graph is printing very well in IE>=10 and chrome but in case of IE9 only the text is getting printed not the complete graph.

Till now I have tried setting the Meta tags of my graph page to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;edge,9;" />
```

Disabled the protected mode of the IE9.

Saving the graph as PDF also giving the text only output.

Answer (score 2):

Add a DOCTYPE to your document, e.g. as the very first write do something like

```
mywindow.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">');
```